# Can we upload two applications with same bundle identifier or same name?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

We have a requirement where we need to upload two apps on apple Appstore having same bundle identifier and name but there functionality is different. So can we achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need same bundle ID?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: @Makyen I think stack overflow is a forum where developers can discuss the problems which they face during app development to deployment. App store submission is a part of deployment. So i don't think this question is out of topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundle identifier needs to be `unique`, the `Application Name` should also be different but they can be closely similar with slight spelling and punctation difference. You can get through but it is **not recommended**.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is **NO**

Apple will not allow you to create 2 apps with same bundle Id on app store. They will not show you same bundle Id once you have created one app with that bundle Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload app with same name and same bundle identifier

Answer (score 0):

i think you will get notified something like below..if you are going to try
with same name

> The Application Name that you provided has already been used. Please
>   provide a unique Application Name.

But you can make a slight change by adding space. punctuation mark etc.